# Как расположить HTML параграфы в окне браузера?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Я хочу расположить две статьи на сайте так, чтобы они были на одном уровне, но у меня они отображаются одна под другой. Как решить проблему?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="c.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><p class="article">JavaScript изначально создавался для того, чтобы сделать web-странички «живыми». Программы на этом языке называются скриптами. В браузере они подключаются напрямую к HTML и, как только загружается страничка – тут же выполняются.</p></li>
        <li><p class="article">JavaScript изначально создавался для того, чтобы сделать web-странички «живыми». Программы на этом языке называются скриптами. В браузере они подключаются напрямую к HTML и, как только загружается страничка – тут же выполняются.</p></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно через `display:inline-block` или `display:flex` — это самое простое решение.

Лучше сначало прочитать хоть какие-то правила `CSS`, а уже потом пробовать что-то писать.

```css
ul li {display:inline-block;width:49%;vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li><p class="article">JavaScript изначально создавался для того, чтобы сделать web-странички «живыми». Программы на этом языке называются скриптами. В браузере они подключаются напрямую к HTML и, как только загружается страничка – тут же выполняются.</p></li>
        <li><p class="article">JavaScript изначально создавался для того, чтобы сделать web-странички «живыми». Программы на этом языке называются скриптами. В браузере они подключаются напрямую к HTML и, как только загружается страничка – тут же выполняются.</p></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="article">JavaScript изначально создавался для того, чтобы сделать web-странички «живыми». Программы на этом языке называются скриптами. В браузере они подключаются напрямую к HTML и, как только загружается страничка – тут же выполняются.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="article">JavaScript изначально создавался для того, чтобы сделать web-странички «живыми». Программы на этом языке называются скриптами. В браузере они подключаются напрямую к HTML и, как только загружается страничка – тут же выполняются.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```